# внешние ключи в mariaDB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, foreign-key

Здравствуйте возникла проблема, в phpadmin у меня есть три таблицы, student,group,student_to_group
таблица student_to_group содержит два поля student_id и group_id( то есть беру id с с таблиц student и group ) , потом я объединил эти три таблицы , так , что если удалить в таблице group группу, то в students и student_to_group удаляться все соответствующие записи. Но теперь я не могу добавлять записи с сайти в бд . С использованием внешних ключей это вообще возможно ? 
Ошибка, которую выводит 
 Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`studentstable`.`students`, CONSTRAINT `students_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `students_to_group` (`student_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: ON DELETE использовал cascade , на ON UPDATE по умолчанию restrict

Answer (score 0):

Отношения внешнего ключа включают родительскую таблицу, в которой хранятся центральные значения данных, и дочернюю таблицу с идентичными значениями, указывающими на ее родителя. Предложение FOREIGN KEY указывается в дочерней таблице.
Он отклонит любую операцию INSERT или UPDATE, которая пытается создать значение внешнего ключа в дочерней таблице, если в родительской таблице нет соответствующего значения ключа-кандидата.